# Como puedo actualizar una imagen en un formulario que guarda datos en dos tablas (Producto e Imagen) LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo dos tablas Producto e imagen y no se como puedo hacer para actualizar los datos de la tabla imagen ... como estoy enviando en el controlador solo me actualiza los datos de la tabla producto. Como debo enviar para que me actualize la imagen??

```
 public function update(UpdateProductoRequest $request, $id){
        try{
            $result = Producto::find($id);
            $result->fill($request->all())->update();

            $resultImagen= Imagen::find($id);
            $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id_producto;
            $resultImagen->update();

            Session::flash('flash_message', config('content.session.update'));
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            Session::flash('error', config('content.session.error'));
            return back()->withInput();
        }
        return redirect()->route('productos.index');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent no utiliza update() para guardar modificaciones en los registros, tienes que utilizar save() para guardar las modificaciones.

```
public function update(UpdateProductoRequest $request, $id)
{
    try{
        $file = $request->file('foto_img');
        $nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
       \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre, file_get_contents($file));

        $result = Producto::find($id);
        $result->fill($request->all());
        $result->save();

        $resultImagen= Imagen::find($id);
        $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id_producto;
        $resultImagen->foto_img = $nombre;
        $resultImagen->save();

        Session::flash('flash_message', config('content.session.update'));
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        Session::flash('error', config('content.session.error'));
        return back()->withInput();
    }
    return redirect()->route('productos.index');
}
```

Comment: tengo que actualizar tambien un archivo (imagen) como debe enviar? porque tendría que reemplazar el archivo que antes se guardó ... gracias de ante mano

Comment: Como puedo actualizar una imagen?? le estoy guardando como tipo varchar ... @Victor Mendoza ,  porfa ayudame

Comment: Buenas, ¿quieres guardar el fichero imagen?

Comment: Si, tu me ayudaste igual en la pregunta que hice de como guardar los datos en dos tablas y en una de ellas era una imagen ... y no se como hacer para actualizar la imagen...le edité el codigo que estoy enviando

Comment: He modificado lo que has editado, mira si te sirve.

Comment: Ya le probé y el error que me da es este: 
FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

Answer (score 0):

va a ver momentos donde el usuario solo actualice los datos por el cual deber realizar la siguiente condición, si el usuario no sube una imagen no ejecute el storage

va reviser el proyecto y encontré varias fallas,

enlaces de drobox https://www.dropbox.com/s/b18faiity7dj0fb/dankarme-dankar-7e08e4f9cf6b.rar?dl=0

para aceder a la URL es por: productos

en el directorio de proyecto **storage\app** se encuentra las imágenes subidas

en la parte de route para mostrar una imagen en storae deber añadir esta linea para acceder a la imagen por medio de la url.
ya que cada registro solo guarda una imagen no veo la necesidad de crear otra tabla y como tiene el modelo se vuelve tedioso, es bueno cuando tiene que subir varias imagenes

```
Route::get('imagene_local/{file}', function ($file) {
    return Storage::disk('local')->response("$file");
});
```

en la vista se deber añadir el siguiente código para añadir

```
@section('content')
    @include('include.alert')
    {!! Form::model($result, ['method' => 'PATCH','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data','route' => ['productos.update', 'id'=>$result->id_producto]]) !!}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Editar Productos') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body"> <!-- ROW 1 -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre_prod">Nombre del Producto</label>
                                {{ Form::text('nombre_prod',$result->nombre_prod,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'nombre_prod'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="color">Color</label>
                                {{ Form::text('color',$result->color,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'color'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="talla">Talla</label>
                                {{ Form::text('talla',$result->talla,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'talla'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                                {{ Form::text('precio',$result->precio,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'precio'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stock">Stock</label>
                                {{ Form::text('stock',$result->stock,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'stock'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre_img">Nombre de Imagen</label>
                                {{ Form::text('nombre_img',$result->imagen->nombre_img,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'nombre_img'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="foto_img">Imagen</label>
                                {{Form::file('foto_img',['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'foto_img'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @include('include.box-footer-update')

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endsection
```

la vista para editar

```
@section('content')
    @include('include.alert')
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'productos.store', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Crear un nuevo Producto') }}</div>
                <div class="card-body"> <!-- ROW 1 -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre_prod">Nombre del Producto</label>
                                {{ Form::text('nombre_prod',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'nombre_prod'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="color">Color</label>
                                {{ Form::text('color',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'color'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="talla">Talla</label>
                                {{ Form::text('talla',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'talla'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="precio">Precio</label>
                                {{ Form::text('precio',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'precio'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stock">Stock</label>
                                {{ Form::text('stock',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'stock'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="nombre_img">Nombre de Imagen</label>
                                {{ Form::text('nombre_img',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'nombre_img'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="stock">Imagen</label>
                                {{Form::file('foto_img',null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
                                @include('include.error_form_element',['name'=>'stock'])
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @include('include.box-footer-create')

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endsection
```

y en el controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProductoRequest;
use App\Imagen;
use App\Producto;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class ProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $results = Producto::get();
        return view('producto.index', ['results' => $results]);
    }
    public function indexCliente()
    {
        $result = Producto::get();
        return view('producto.view-cliente', ['result' => $result]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('producto.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {



        // INSERT
        $result= new Producto();
        $result->fill($request->all());
        $result->save();

        // aquí guardas las imagenes
        $resultImagen= new Imagen();
        $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id_producto;

        $file2 = Input::file('foto_img');
        if(isset($file2)) {
            $nombres = time() . str_random(5) . '.' . $file2->getClientOriginalExtension();
            \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombres, \File::get($file2));
            $resultImagen->foto_img = $nombres;
        }


        //$file = Input::file('foto_img');
        //$nombre = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        //\Storage::disk('local')->put($nombre, \File::get($file));
        //$resultImagen->foto_img = $nombre;
        $resultImagen->nombre_img=$request->nombre_img;
        //$resultImagen->fill($request->all());
        $resultImagen->save();

        Session::flash('message', config('content.session.create'));
        return redirect()->route('productos.index');
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $result = Producto::find($id);
        return view('producto.view', ['result' => $result]);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $result = Producto::find($id);
        $result->imagen=Imagen::where('idProducto',$id)->first(); 

        return view('producto.edit', ['result' => $result]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

            $result = Producto::find($id);
            $result->fill($request->all());
            $result->save();

            $resultImagen=Imagen::where('idProducto',$id)->first();
            //$resultImagen= Imagen::find($id);

            $file2 = Input::file('foto_img');
            if (isset($file2)) {
                $nombres = time() . str_random(5) . '.' . $file2->getClientOriginalExtension();
                \Storage::disk('local')->put($nombres, \File::get($file2));
                $resultImagen->foto_img = $nombres;
            }

            $resultImagen->idProducto = $result->id_producto;
            //dd($resultImagen);
            $resultImagen->save();

        try{
            Session::flash('flash_message', config('content.session.update'));
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            Session::flash('error', config('content.session.error'));
            return back()->withInput();
        }
        return redirect()->route('productos.index');
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        // busca tabla padre
        $result = Producto::find($id);

        // busca tabla hijo y se borra
        $resultImagen = Imagen::find($result->id_producto);
        $resultImagen->delete();

        // borrar el padre
        $result->delete();

        return redirect('/productos')->with('success', 'Stock has been deleted Successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, le probé el código, no me da errores pero no se actualiza ... le envié un dd($resultImg) para ver que me da de resultado y no se actualiza ...

Comment: si quiere me manda el codigo en teamviewer para hace una conexion remota

Comment: si tiene problema con el codigo, me envia un enlaces con los archivos del codigo fuente y aquí le hacemos pruebas a ver que error tiene

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/dankarme/ en este enlace tengo subido el proyecto ... te agradecería mucho que me puedas ayudar ...y si es con teamviewer como nos comunicariamos?

Comment: me puedes ayudar??

Comment: ya solucione el problema

Comment: En verdad?? como puedo arreglarlo?? si puedes podemos hacerlo por teamviewer?? @marcos porfavor